# How to convert a mapped generic type to an union of tuples in typescript

Tags: typescript, templates, generics

I'm creating something similar to `Object.entries` and I would like it to be more strongly typed. I want to make a type which given an object returns strongly typed union of 2-tuples of that object's properties.

Currently

```js
export type Entries<T> = [keyof T, T[keyof T]][];

Entries<{first: number, second: string}> = ["first" | "second", number | string][]
```

What I would like

```js
Entries<{first: number, second: string}> = ["first", number] | ["second", string][]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an actual [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) with the `{[K in keyof T]: ...}` syntax, and then [look up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) its properties:

```
export type Entries<T> = { [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]] }[keyof T][];

type E = Entries<{ first: number; second: string }>;
// type E = (["first", number] | ["second", string])[]
```

---

You could also use a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) like this one that requires a helper type alias to work:

```
type EntriesHelper<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? [K, T[K]] : never;
type Entries<T> = Array<EntriesHelper<T, keyof T>>;

type E = Entries<{ first: number; second: string }>;
// type E = (["first", number] | ["second", string])
```

or like this one that uses [inference in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) instead of a helper:

```
type Entries<T> = Array<
  keyof T extends infer K ? (K extends keyof T ? [K, T[K]] : never) : never
>;

type E = Entries<{ first: number; second: string }>;
// type E = (["first", number] | ["second", string])[]
```

---

They all produce the same output here, but might act differently in the face of optional properties or other edge case, so be careful.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAZA9mg1hAJgVRgFkQYZckBvAKCSQgA8Y0AnAFyVYE8ykBRYVswCW0ADwAVAHxIAvJSQBtANJIhwJNk5oAZknEBdAFyKlAGj3L9+pAF8FmnXv0L9Abio0O3ZL1l8BwmIUSNpCzFCsxsAArmAARhDMrkhQEPBowDjGEcLAAOa2ku60APQlXjy+cgAUCgBEoeGsdeYx8YnWAD6KdanpmS0pgmp5+gCULlQ2HqCQsAjIACJCOUJx0axCAG4QAMIZOEKbGSAANgDqRwAWABIQp2TMlJ5clQEiUHcPiRLmStJyFQMVgQTJQDQQLS6cRIAD8JnM4ks1iiEB2SRe3n8wzEUj8AEFmMwQJxRPwcZ97o9fhCoXpJEUPLRXj4-OTAlBRMFGhEorEEkkUmkDtlhvlCsUkGUKqyavUec1WvyOkhuvU+gdBqt8uMpjNwNA4IgkMtVutNjt9pkjkIThdrmgNl9Hs9mVj2R8JACkITiaTPLQHNC6PQQWDVMBtIkkCp4dUgaHQThwUG9HCERYlFYkKj0WMc0hgGjEp5GZjKmz3kEQmFeYXlYKNZlRbkCjZGaVyiy+H5ag1a4r6+1mF0ek2cFqxaMJvo9UA)

Comment: Using a temporary mapped type in the middle is a great solution to this. Kudos

Comment: You can also do it with [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) but this way is more straightforward.  Also keep in mind the general [caveat](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208) about strongly typing things like `Object.entries`.  Cheers!